# Minor ticks in log axis missing

Tags: pgfplots, axis

I'm missing some minor y ticks in a logarithmic `pgfplots` axis:

[image]

This has been generated with:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymode=log,
    ymax=31,
]
    \addplot[only marks] coordinates {(0,0.1) (1,11)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Notice that `ymax=31`, so I would expect minor y ticks at y = 20 and y = 30.

If I change `ymax` slightly to 32, it works as expected:

[image]

**Question:** What could be the problem here, and how to fix it?

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymode=log,
    ymax=31,
]
    \addplot[only marks] coordinates {(0,0.1) (1,11)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymode=log,
    ymax=32,
]
    \addplot[only marks] coordinates {(0,0.1) (1,11)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interestingly. You can solve this by explicit defined `enlargelimits`. For example `enlargelimits=0.05,`

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for the suggestion. But still, you have to make `enlargelimits` large enough, right? E.g. `enlarge y limits=0.004` works, but `enlarge y limits=0.003` does not. So there seems to be some magic threshold ...

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. You could report it on `pgfplots`' [issue tracker](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues).

Comment: I _think_ that I have seen this "bug" before. Unfortunately I can't remember if it was here on TeX.SX or elsewhere. I also already had a look at the issue tracker, but couldn't find it there. So I agree to add this to the tracker.

Comment: I think I have "found" it. Without checking it again, have a look if the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/569726/95441 is related. If yes, we could close the question as duplicate.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Thanks a lot, Stefan, for your link. However, I don't think it is a duplicate. Maybe related, but I can't really judge. In the linked question it seems that the problem is a too narrow y range. My y axis spans almost 3 orders of magnitude. If you do think it solves my problem, I'm afraid I'll have to ask you to elaborate more.

Comment: As a work around, I use `extra y ticks = {20,30}, extra y tick labels = {}, extra tick style = {tickwidth = \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/minor tick length}`. However, for the original problem I will probably issue a bug report as recommended.

Comment: For the record:  This issue was reported as bug at <https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues/435>.